# Page not redirecting to Previous page after login

Tags: c#, asp.net

Page not redirecting to Previous page after login .
Every time after session time out , page is redirecting to login page after login page its going to home page not redirecting to previous page
im using this below code but its not working.

code

```
page_load code
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["ReturnUrl"] = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            string Rurl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];


                   }
button event code

     if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
               {
                    Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
                }
           else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
                }
```

Comment: you need to maintain query string in the login page URL like this /login.aspx?ReturnUrl="previouspage.aspx" otherwise Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] always return null and else part will execute.

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Comment: how to set previous page. it will be dynamic so what to write in/login.aspx?ReturnUrl="???" . previouspage.aspx is a static page @Sain Pradeep

Comment: in middle of the session when session time out happens its asking for login page then when we are logging its going to home page. how to store previous page url and redirect to that previous page @yogi970

Comment: post the code where you are checking for the session

Comment: are you sure that you have previous page name in `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]`

Comment: where are you setting "Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" ? Show that code

Comment: im not sure where to write the code to set Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]. i have lot of pages where to set Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] @Justcode

Comment: @krishnamohan its obvious that you are setting up the querystring into the viewstate...now, you just need to use viewstate in the whole page where you need it. you are storing the querystring values into the viewstate and it retains unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach

#### Use this code on every page (not on login page)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["prevUrl"] = Request.Url; //Save every page url in this sesssion when page loads
    //your code from here....
}
```

> You can use Request.Url.AbsoluteUri for getting absolute URL.

#### On login page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After  successfull log in
    if(Session["prevUrl"]!=null){
    Response.Redirect((string)Session["prevUrl"]); //Will redirect to previous page
    }else{
    Response.Redirect("To your home page");
    }
}
```

> Do not forget to clear this "PrevURL" session  on LogOut

Comment: but small change i did then its worked -
Response.Redirect(Session["prevUrl"].Tostring());

Comment: You know this will fail on session time out?